# Karate: call feature with result and share context

Tags: karate

If I use `call read(A.feature)` from feature B then feature A can modify the context of B (e.g. cookies)

On the other hand, if I use `def variable = call read(A.feature)` from feature B feature A will not modify the context of B.

How can I call feature A from feature B returning a variable and ALSO modifying the context of B? Does this design (using `def` not only for returning a result, but also for allowing context modification) allow it someway?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify context, any variables created will be automatically "global". Which means you don't need to return anything, you will get *any* variable created in A from B.

If the above does not answer your question, please assume that Karate does not support what you want.